# How do you pronounce "cURL," the computer utility?

Tags: pronunciation, computing, programming

Are there programmers here? I'd like to know how you guys pronounce [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/).
Because I don't live in a country that uses English, I haven't heard it yet.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[According to the authors of the library](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html),

> We pronounce curl and cURL with an initial k sound: [kurl].

This same FAQ notes that one of the reasons for which the name was chosen was "[t]he fact it can also be pronounced 'see URL'", an obvious pun on the use of the library, which as you know is to retrieve web resources.

For what it's worth, I always pronounce it with the initial k sound, as in the English word "curl."

Answer (score 7):

I am a programmer and I would prefer to pronounce it spelled out as "see you are ell".

Comment: And how do you pronounce "URL"? ;-)

Comment: You say the letters:  U.R.L.

Comment: I pronounce it as "U" "R" "L"

Comment: I've heard some technical people say _yurl_ instead of _U-R-L_, but they are a small minority.

Comment: @silves89 "earl" is more common than "yurl". Also see: http://tidbits.com/article/4514

Comment: If I start by saying "see, you are e…" it'll probably kick off a fight for being judgemental - "What did you call me?" No, no, it's kurl every time!

Answer (score 2):

I use cURL as a verb, as in "*kurl* the service again to check that the GET is idempotent." And I type cURL all the time - it's just much easier to think and say *kurl* than *C-U-R-L*.